# What is wrong with my struct typedef causing "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type?"

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, data-structures, dereference

Im having trouble with my project of the university when i compile my files they are 5 (api.c api.h datastruct.c datastruct.h and main.c) with MakeFile the problem is in the datastruct.c and datastruct.h when compiles this functions:

```
vertex new_vertex() {
    /*This functions allocate memorie for the new struct vertex wich save 
    the value of the vertex X from the edge, caller should free this memorie*/

    vertex new_vertex = NULL;

    new_vertex = calloc(1, sizeof(vertex_t));
    new_vertex->back = NULL;
    new_vertex->forw = NULL;
    new_vertex->nextvert = NULL;

    return(new_vertex);   
}
```

and in the file datastruct.h i have the structure definition:

```
typedef struct vertex_t *vertex;
typedef struct edge_t *alduin;

typedef struct _edge_t{
    vertex vecino;      //Puntero al vertice que forma el lado
    u64 capacidad;      //Capacidad del lado
    u64 flujo;          //Flujo del lado       
    alduin nextald;          //Puntero al siguiente lado
}edge_t;

typedef struct _vertex_t{
    u64 verx;   //first vertex of the edge
    alduin back; //Edges stored backwawrd
    alduin forw; //Edges stored forward
    vertex nextvert;

}vertex_t;
```

i cant see the problem datastruct.h is included in datastruct.c!!!
The error on compiler is:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c99   -c -o datastruct.o datastruct.c
datastruct.c: In function ‘new_vertex’:
datastruct.c:10:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
datastruct.c:11:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
datastruct.c:12:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Comment: What's the problem? Please show the error message what compiler output.

Comment: Comment on style: typedef'ing pointers is in my opinion a big mistake because in C it is very important to know what you are dealing with. I'd just suck it up and type `struct vertex_t*` everywhere I needed one.

Comment: Also you use `calloc` to allocate your memory and `calloc` sets the memory to 0. So you don't need all those NULL assignments.

Comment: Also, suggestion for future learning and debugging: you should have created a new empty project and played around with different ways of declaring structs and typedefs. You would likely have found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Read carefully what you wrote:

```
vertex new_vertex = NULL; // Declare an element of type 'vertex'
```

But what is `vertex`?

```
typedef struct vertex_t *vertex; // A pointer to a 'struct vertex_t'
```

So what is a `struct vertex_t`? Well, it doesn't exist. You defined the following:

```
typedef struct _vertex_t {
    ...
} vertex_t;
```

That's two definitions:

1. `struct _vertex_t`
2. `vertex_t`

No such thing as `struct vertex_t` (the reasoning is similar for `edge`). Change your typedefs to either:

```
typedef vertex_t *vertex;
typedef edge_t *edge;
```

Or:

```
typedef struct _vertex_t *vertex;
typedef struct _edge_t *edge;
```

---

Unrelated to your problem and as said in the comments by user Zan Lynx, allocating with `calloc` will zero all the members of your struct, therefore initializing them with `NULL` is superflous.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
typedef struct vertex_t *vertex;
typedef struct edge_t *alduin;
```

it should be:

```
typedef struct _vertex_t *vertex;
typedef struct _edge_t *alduin;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it.

Your problem is in your typedef. In C typedef creates a new type name. Struct names however, are not type names.

So if you change `typedef struct vertex_t *vertex` into `typedef vertex_t *vertex` it will fix that error message.